# Посоветуйте ооп форум на php

Tags: php, ооп, forum

Никак не могу найти нормальный форум, хотя бы с минимальным функционалом, но с нормальным кодом, а то от лапши phpbb и иже с ним тошнит =\

Comment: Мне кажется, вы мало знаете об ооп, шаблонизации и т.п., если вас тошнит от популярного движка. Если хотите попроще, посмотрите phpBB-WAP и прочие WAP движки, в них всё проще.

Comment: @psix-dev я нашел сорс за две минуты в гугле  
https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/develop/phpBB/search.php  
и это явно не ок, сколько бы там коммитов в репе не было

Answer (score 1):

Вот, как вариант https://github.com/fluxbb/fluxbb/tree/2.0 , вполне интересно.

Comment: пасиб, а на каком он движке - никак не вспомню - laravel?

Comment: Не за что :) да и не надо всё помнить, достаточно адекватно ориентироваться в коде https://github.com/fluxbb/fluxbb/blob/2.0/composer.json#L7

Comment: в результате поисков был найден вот такой симпотишный форум https://github.com/esotalk/esoTalk , сейчас как раз занимаюсь его интеграцией с kohana framework